# Load partial pages using custom-directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, custom-directive

- I have nav-bar containing links `link 1`, `link 2`.
- On selection of each link I want to inject partial page in the content section.
- I want to achieve this using `Custom-directive` in AngularJS.

I searched and got this piece of code snippet.
But again, i don't know to inject partial pages.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('clicker', function(){
    var link = function(scope){
      scope.showMessage = function(){
        alert('you clicked the directive!');
      };
    };
    return {
       link: link
       template: "<button ng-click='showMessage()'>Click me!</button>"
    };
});
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have updated my question with tried code.